# Adding a tag failed

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777244/documentdb-linq-match-multiple-child-objects), and gave it 4 tags.

`c#`, `linq`, `azure-documentdb`, `azure-cosmosdb`

After saving the question I noticed it only had three tags.

`c#`, `linq`, `azure-documentdb`

I made an edit, adding some text to the body and adding the `azure-cosmosdb` tag.

After saving I noticed it still only had 3 tags.

`c#`, `linq`, `azure-documentdb`

At this point I started to question my sanity. Maybe I failed to add the `azure-cosmosdb` tag the previous two times, so I made an edit where the only change was adding that tag.

I double checked it was the right tag, and that the text in the tag box had turned in to a div (indicating that it was a recognized tag). Indeed, I even selected the tag from the list of suggestions, rather than typing it all myself.

I read the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-cosmosdb/info) to make sure it wasn't an alias of `azure-documentdb` (which it isn't, and shouldn't be).

And after saving the edit, it still only had 3 tags.

Interestingly the "tag only" edit isn't in the edit history. So it appears to have accepted my edit, with no warnings or errors, but then not applied it.

I had a search and found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34732/why-is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-tags), which suggests there is a limit of 5 tags.

I have 3 tags, and want 4 tags, and received no error message saying I was trying to add too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [azure-cosmosdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb) is a synonym of [azure-documentdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-documentdb), as you can see in the azure-documentdb synonyms page:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-documentdb/synonyms

This means that whenever you tag with [azure-cosmosdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb), it gets automatically replaced with [azure-documentdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-documentdb), which was already in the question.

It is in fact misleading that the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-cosmosdb/info) is in place, since it is difficult to access through the question and there is no visual indication that it is a synonym of another tag unless you click [azure-cosmosdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb), to see the list of questions belong to [azure-documentdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-documentdb).

Comment: Great find thank you! This is why I checked the info page for the tag, I expected any synonyms to be listed there. It's also unfortunate that there's no message to the author as to why the tag just disappears.

Comment: @AndyJ indeed this may need some UX improvement to make it more prominent. What I do is to browse through the questions of the tag; there, you'll immediately notice if it is a synonym of another one.

Comment: I'm writing up a feature suggestion for this. And I'll accept this as the answer when the acceptance delay timer has finished. Many thanks.