# Make tag synonym replacement obvious when it happens

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

I recently asked an SO:M [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351319/adding-a-tag-failed#351320), about an SO question, where I had tags "disappear" upon posting.

I was vaguely aware of tag synonyms so I checked the [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-cosmosdb/info), but there was no indication that it was a synonym.

Apparently there is a [separate page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-documentdb/synonyms) that shows this, but there are no links to it from the tags when asking a question, nor from their info page.

When I posted the question, and subsequent edits, they were all silently accepted, with no indication of why the tag was being removed.

This could be fixed by checking for synonyms when adding tags. For example, since I already had `azure-documentdb`, adding `azure-cosmosdb` should have raised an error.

If that's not feasible, then informing the author after they have posted the question/edit seems reasonable. The duplicated tags are obviously detected since the superfluous one is removed, so the response could indicate to the UI that the author needs to be informed of the change.

Comment: Do note that if you go to the page (the list of questions that have that tag) you will see a synonyms link on the far right with a number that indicates the number of synonyms.

Comment: Should have either a message after adding, or some indicator on tags that are merely synonyms, and won't be kept.

Comment: It could be as simple as striking through the synonymized tag. Add hover text that says something like "`azure-cosmosdb` is a synonym of `azure-documentdb`".